# Upload multipart file using Request Library in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, request, automated-tests, robotframework

I am trying to upload a file using the `Request Library` in python. Although I receive `code 200`, the file is still not getting upload.

The same thing works totally fine with [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/).

Here is the python code-

```
import requests 
test_url = "https://api.company.net/file/upload/"
my_file = open("C://Certificate.pdf", "rb")       
login_data =  {"email":"admin@company.org", "password":"abc123!"}       
header= {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data",    "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br"}     
s = requests.Session() 
login = s.post("https://api.company.net/session/login", json=login_data) 
test_response = s.post(test_url, headers=header, files= {"file": my_file})
print (login.status_code) 
print (login.content) 
print(test_response.text)
```

Output -

> 200
>
> b'{"ok":true,"status":200,"data":"Login in successful","errors":null}'

Tried also without explicitly specifying the headers, but still, the file doesn't get uploaded.

My robot framework code is -

> ```
>  *** Variable *** 
>
>  &{headers_file}      Content-Type=multipart/form-data   X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest    Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate,be
>
>  *** Test Cases ***
>
> &{file}    Create Dictionary    file   ${CURDIR}/Certificate.pdf   flowChunkNumber    1   flowChunkSize    1048576    flowCurrentChunkSize    25582   flowTotalSize    25582    flowIdentifier   25582-Certificatepdf    flowFilename   Certificate.pdf    flowRelativePath  Certificate.pdf    flowTotalChunks    1
> ${test_uri}    Set Variable    /file/upload/
> ${response}    POST On Session    api_session    ${test_uri}    files=&{file}    headers=&{headers_file}
> #VALIDATION
> ${status}=    Convert To String    ${response.status_code}
> Should Be Equal    ${status}    200
> ```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Access the file in `request.FILES['file']`

Comment: Verify that `/session/login` returns `cookie` header and doesn't use some other special headers for session/jwt-token.

Comment: @ont.rif yes, it `/session/login` returns `cookie`

<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie PHPSESSID=h476oj9i6mboiutiuree1bk2ko for api.company.net/>]>

Comment: Try to output `test_response.status_code` and `test_response.content`, also verify that `https://api.company.net/file/upload/` and `https://api.company.net/file/upload` (wiithout trailing slash) is configured to be equal routes.

Comment: with Trailing Slash
---`test_response.status_code` is `200`---
---`test_response.content` is `b' ' `---

Without Trailing Slash
---`test_response.status_code` is `200`---
---`test_response.content` is ---`b'{"ok":true,"status":200,"data":"REST API SERVER INDEX, Version:1.9.9.2","errors":null}'`---  but it should go with the trailing slash